# clearInterval clearing two intervals

Tags: javascript

I can't run `clearInterval` for my functions. I use them to scroll the window by firing `setInterval` with function that fires `scrollLeft`. The code:

```
function scrollSpan() {
    $('nav#scrolling').children().css('width',config.windowWidth/10+'px');
    var inter;

    $('nav#scrolling').children('span').hover(function() {
        var value;

        if($(this).is('.scrollLeft')) {
            value = '-=50'
        } else {
            value = '+=50'
        }

        inter = setInterval(function() {
            $('body, html').animate({
                scrollLeft: value
            }, 50);
        },0)
    })

    $('nav#scrolling').children('span').mouseleave(function() {
        clearInterval(inter)
    })
}
```

Problem is, when `mouseleave` is triggered, interval doesn't stop.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FpX4M/

Comment: At a guess, you are probably setting more than one interval and only clearing the latest one. Change you code to check that `inter` isn't already running before starting it again.

Comment: well `inter` is a shared variable so it gets overwritten. Makes sense why it does not work. Clear it before you set it and you probably want to stop animate().

Comment: @epascarello: Yes, that's the problem. The variable is overwritten, but the associated timer isn't stopped. It runs forever (or until you move to another page)

Comment: now `inter` is declared only once and it still doesn't work

Comment: try using a differnt variable for timeout handeler of scrollleft and scrollright, and clear both.

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 Tried using `intervalLeft` and `intervalRight` and clearing both, but this didn't work either.

Comment: can you add your html and script to JsFiddle.net ?

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 link's in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `hover` where you should be using `mouseenter`.  When only one handler is passed to `hover` that handler is called **both** on enter and leave.  So your `hover` is called twice (once entering and once leaving) but your `mouseleave` is only called once.  This is why even though one interval is cleared, the other remains.

See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), in particular the signature added in v1.4 which takes only a single handler (scrolldown).

**EDIT:  Jsfiddles with proof:**

http://jsfiddle.net/FpX4M/1/

Open your console and see that the handlers trigger twice and that interval continues.

http://jsfiddle.net/FpX4M/2/

In the console you will now see only one firing of the handler and then the intervals stop on leave.

Comment: I tried this with `mouseneter` at the beginning, but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm only able to test it in firefox at the moment, but in my 2nd fiddle above the interval does not continue to run after your mouse leaves.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole scope is a little wonky. Try something like this:

```
var inter;

function scrollSpan() {
    $('nav#scrolling').children().css('width',config.windowWidth/10+'px');
}

$('nav#scrolling').children('span').hover(function() {
    var value;

    if($(this).is('.scrollLeft')) {
        value = '-=50'
    } else {
        value = '+=50'
    }

    inter = setInterval(function() {
        $('body, html').animate({
            scrollLeft: value
        }, 50);
    },0)
});

$('nav#scrolling').children('span').mouseleave(function() {
    clearInterval(inter)
});
```

You need to make sure the `inter` variable is accessible outside of the function. Also, generally, state functions shouldn't be assigned within functions unless you're changing them rapidly - and it doesn't look like you're detaching them anywhere. The only things that need to be in the function are things that will be repeated. Maybe add a `clearInterval(inter);` right before your `inter = setInterval...` to make sure no old intervals persist.

Comment: Can you post this in a jsfiddle? The best we can do without full context is make an educated guess.

Comment: I did, it's in the question.